# how to remove \ from json data?

Tags: javascript, json, wcf

I use .net wcf services in my angular project, but i get the response like that:

```
{
  "stateResult": "[{\"state_id\":\"1\",\"state_name\":\"Madhya Pradesh\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"},{\"state_id\":\"2\",\"state_name\":\"Gujrat\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"},{\"state_id\":\"3\",\"state_name\":\"Goa\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"},{\"state_id\":\"4\",\"state_name\":\"Maharashtra\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"}]"
}
```

but the desired result;

```
[{"state_id":"1","state_name":"Madhya Pradesh","IsActive":"True"},{"state_id":"2","state_name":"Gujrat","IsActive":"True"},{"state_id":"3","state_name":"Goa","IsActive":"True"},{"state_id":"4","state_name":"Maharashtra","IsActive":"True"}]
```

Comment: You should modify the .net wcf services

Comment: You should just fix whatever's generating that response.

Comment: How are you creating this JSON?  You're creating it wrong.  Removing the slashes is just hiding the problem.

Comment: Do not convert your object to string. That will send the correct JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just parse that result, like so:

```
let result = {
  "stateResult": "[{\"state_id\":\"1\",\"state_name\":\"Madhya Pradesh\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"},{\"state_id\":\"2\",\"state_name\":\"Gujrat\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"},{\"state_id\":\"3\",\"state_name\":\"Goa\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"},{\"state_id\":\"4\",\"state_name\":\"Maharashtra\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"}]"
}
result = JSON.parse(result.stateResult);
```

Comment: I tried the above result to parse and its working fine but If my data looks like below then i am not able to parse.

{
  "stateResult": ["{\"state_id\":\"1\",\"state_name\":\"Madhya Pradesh\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"}","{\"state_id\":\"2\",\"state_name\":\"Gujrat\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"}","{\"state_id\":\"3\",\"state_name\":\"Goa\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"}","{\"state_id\":\"4\",\"state_name\":\"Maharashtra\",\"IsActive\":\"True\"}"]
}

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

To transform a string to JSON you can use `JSON.parse(jsonString);` but as already stated, you should send the JSON object itself and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the json data is double encoded, for example in php I was wrongly doing `php_encode()` twice.

Not sure from the question who is doing the encoding on your side but it looks like this may be the case for you too.